# How can I set single spacing in todonotes?

Tags: errors, macros, setspace, todonotes

**Question**

How can I `\renewcommand{\todo}` to give single spacing in the todonotes of an otherwise double spaced document?

**What I have tried**

The [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) (p. 11, section 1.8.6)  suggests that something like this should work (with [todonotes.sty](http://ctan.binkerton.com/ctan.content.php?filename=/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.sty) in the proper directory), but it doesn't:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}              
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=white,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\smalltodo}[2][] 
    {\todo[caption={#2}, #1]
    {\begin{spacing}{0.5}#2\end{spacing}}} 
\begin{document}
\smalltodo[inline]{testing todonotes here with single spacing}
\end{document}
```

giving the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\todo [caption={##2}, ##1] {\begin {spacing}{0.5}##2\end {spacing}} \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xargdef.
```

But I can't figure out the error.

Once I get this to work, can I just replace `\newcommand{\smalltodo}` with `\renewcommand{\todo}` ?

Comment: Your example compiles fine on my system (both with TeX Live 2010 and 2009). What versions of todonotes and setspace are you using?

Comment: @Caramdir I was trying to compile the test case on LaTeXLab, I see that it does compile on my desktop installation, but am not sure how to tell what versions of the packages I am using.

Comment: on your desktop you can see the version in `todonotes.sty` (the optional argument to `\ProvidesPackage` at the top) for LaTeXLab I have no idea.

Comment: @Caramdir okay, this provides me with a date: `\ProvidesPackage{todonotes}[2009/04/02]`, I was looking for a version number.

Comment: This is the same version I have installed and it works for me. Strange.

Comment: I have the same problem with version 2011/10/26; @David, did you ever figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I don't know why it doesn't compile for you, here is an answer to your second question:

No, you can't just use `\renewcommend` as that would create an infinite loop; every call to `\todo` would have another call to `\todo` inside it. However, `\todo` is actually just an alias for `\@todo` (apparently the author thought that people might want to redefine it), so you can simply do the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
    \@todo[caption={#2}, #1]{\begin{spacing}{0.5}#2\end{spacing}}%
} 
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks for your help. What does `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` do?

Comment: @David: per default, `@` does not work in command names in the “end user” document, but only works in internal (class/package) files. The `\makeatletter` changes that and `\makeatother` resets it.

Comment: @Caramidir Thanks for your answer and explanation

Comment: @Caramdir I implemented this solution but when I insert a todo after a `\newline` command and a line break in Latex source code (so just at the beginning of a new paragraph) the line space between the previous and the new paragraph disappears. Any idea why is happening, and/or a workaround?